# base vs Previous in Virtual Path Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When you register a VirtualPathProvider, you still want the previous VPPs to work.  I have seen this done in two ways:  one is using `base` (e.g., `if base.FileExists(virtualPath)`) and the other is using `Previous` (e.g., `if Previous.FileExists(virtualPath)`).  What is the difference between these, and is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, when you register a `VirtualPathProvider` with the `HostingEnvironment`, it provides the current `VirtualPathProvider` to the `Initialize` method of your `VirtualPathProvider`.  This initialize method saves the provided VPP to the field `_previous`.

The virtual methods provided by the base class `VirtualPathProvider` use `_previous` in the following manner:

```
public virtual bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
{
    return this._previous != null && this._previous.FileExists(virtualPath);
}
```

Each method checks to make sure that `_previous` is valued, then provides the relevant response.  It seems like calling `base` is safer than calling `Previous`, because `base` will do all the `null` checking for you.